# What is the model of boost threading library

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, pthreads, boost-thread

Which is the threading model of c++ boost threading library use ?
`1:1 (Kernel-level threading)`
`N:1 (User-level threading)`
`M:N (Hybrid threading)`

The difference between these models (from wiki): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Models

I checked the boost site and it does not mentioned about the threading model it uses.
I guess it is a 1:1, because it does not provide function like `yield` or `reschedule` ，but i'm not sure...

Comment: user-level threading is implemented in boost coroutine? also may depends on platform.

Comment: +1. It seems to be a good question... but I'm not sure if I understood it, so could please elaborate on the differences between models mentioned in your question? Or, provide us with a link which explains them.

Comment: @Nawaz http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Models

Comment: @BryanChen So boost.thread is 1:1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is native threads, namely, it will use platform threads, at least in Linux, Windows and Mac.

As far as I know, the thread mapping is going to be 1:1 with a kernel thread in Windows, Linux and MAC for each spawned thread.

I am not sure if for other platforms it could be implemented in other ways, but I don't know of any non-kernel thread implemenation with boost.thread API.

For user-level "threads", with cooperative multitasking, boost.coroutine can be used. There is also the upcoming boost.fiber library, which is almost like boost.coroutine, but it adds a user-level "thread" (which is a fiber in library terminology) API and a user-level fiber scheduler.

- You can find boost.fiber [here](https://github.com/olk/boost-fiber).
- You can find boost.coroutine [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: thx for the links, a great help. is there any links or codes that declares boost.thread use platform threads?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread.html you can see all config macros in there.